# Sheets Protection with Script in Drive Team

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I'm trying to run a protection script. The file is based in a Drive Team.
The script is run from a button in a sheet.
The user has to duplicate a "master sheet" input data and press the button.

The script below:

```
var MainOwner = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var CoOwner = "pippo@pippo.com";
var SheetName = "Test";
var UserOK = [
    MainOwner, 
    CoOwner
  ];
var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setDescription(Sheet_Name +'_Protection')
  .addEditors(UserOK);
```

At the end the sheets is protected but editors are all the users allowed in the the Drive Team.

I'm not able to understand what is wrong in the flow.
Thanks

Comment: "_I'm not able to understand what is wrong in the flow_" Just what is your problem? it is not clear at all.